# Erro "Illegal string offset" ao chamar usort em dados do banco

Tags: php, sql, array, mysqli

Estou tentando ordenar o resultado por uma coluna específica de uma array de dados do banco.

```
 function cmp($a, $b) {
 return strcmp($a['usu_codigo'], $b['usu_codigo']);
  };

usort($usu_info_coluna, "cmp");
```

Dando um `var_dump` em `$usu_info_Coluna`, ele retorna:

```
array(21) { ["usu_codigo"]=> int(1) ["usu_nome"]=> string(5) "LUANN" ["usu_senha"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$I4RqdKD/cOwRDNpFgtIbWeVirNIfxHPREMEklGaBuONGRZMtQfUgq" ["usu_sobrenome"]=> string(5) "SOUSA" ["usu_cpf"]=> string(11) "12345678998" ["usu_rg"]=> string(9) "123456789" ["usu_nasc"]=> string(10) "2018-10-22" ["usu_endereco"]=> string(4) "AV 2" ["usu_numero"]=> string(2) "97" ["usu_bairro"]=> string(8) "BLOCO D2" ["usu_cep"]=> string(8) "11900000" ["usu_cidade"]=> string(11) "REGISTRO-SP" ["usu_uf"]=> string(2) "SP" ["usu_tel"]=> string(10) "1338226293" ["usu_cel"]=> string(11) "13997821923" ["usu_genero"]=> string(9) "Masculino" ["usu_situacao"]=> string(5) "ativo" ["usu_email"]=> string(22) "LUANNSOUSA15@GMAIL.COM" ["usu_indicador_codigo"]=> NULL ["usu_datacadastro"]=> string(10) "2018-10-22" ["usu_nivel"]=> string(3) "adm" }
```

No que eu errei usando o usort? Mudei e mudei o código do usort, mas sempre me retorna um erro diferente, e acredito que isso foi o mais próximo que cheguei.

***UPDATE 0***:
Essa é a query preparada que utilizo para a consulta:

```
$_SESSION['codigo'] = 1; 
$usu_codigo = $_SESSION['codigo'];
$usu_situacao = 'ativo';

$stmt3 = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = ?');
$stmt3->bind_param('i', $usu_codigo);
$stmt3->execute();
$usu_ult5_cad = $stmt3->get_result();
```

Exibindo através de uma tabela:

```
<?php

$limit = 2;
while($limit -- && $coluna_ult5 = $usu_ult5_cad->fetch_array()){

    ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $coluna_ult5['usu_codigo']; ?><br></th>
      <td><?php echo $coluna_ult5['usu_nome']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $coluna_ult5['usu_sobrenome']; ?><br></td>
    </tr>                                               
<?php }
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro passo de tudo é tentar traduzir o erro para saber do que se trata.

`Illegal string offset` é retornado quando você tenta obter um `offset` de uma string, passando uma `string` por parâmetro.

Veja:

```
$a = 'wallace';

var_dump($a[0]); // string 'w'

var_dump($a['string']); // Erro: Illegal string offset 'string' on line 1
```

Veja o teste no [ideone](https://ideone.com/OcGr7r).

Isso é porque o operador `[]` funciona tanto para `array`, como para `string` em PHP. No caso da `string` você consegue obter o caractere de acordo com a posição passada.

Porém, se você passar uma string, isso gera um erro. Isso é algo que o PHP permite para strings e poucas pessoas sabem.

O que está acontecendo dentro da sua função é basicamente isso.

Quando você passa o seu `array` para `usort`, ele vai pegar os itens do seu `array` de `2` e `2` e passá-los por parâmetro do callback de `usort`.

Exemplificando o caso do seu `array`, ele está assim:

```
  ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3]
```

Se você passar esse `array` para `usort`, o `callback` colocaria `1` em `$a` e `2` em `$b`.

E por isso está dando erro Illegal string offset. Pois você assumiu que dentro do callback estava passando um `array`, mas na verdade está passando strings ou inteiros.

Para poder dar certo do jeito que está tentando fazer, o seu `array` deveria estar assim:

```
  [
        ['usu_codigo' => 1, /** resto do array **/],
        ['usu_codigo'   => 2, /** resto do array **/],
        ['usu_codigo'   => 3, /** resto do array **/],
  ]
```

Veja um exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/kjorAb)

Comment: Só que essa ordenação do array vai fazer com que eu tenha que alterar a query original?

Comment: Depende. Qual é a query original? Se achar viável, edite sua pergunta e coloque ela  lá, pra eu dar uma analisada

Comment: O que eu realmente quero fazer é filtrar os resultados da tabela, por exemplo, limitar a 2 registros (tudo ok) e ordenar por ordem crescente/decrescente por uma coluna, "usu_codigo" por exemplo. Não quero ordenar pela query utilizando um order by porque não quero ter que fazer uma query que busque os mesmos resultados só pra ordenar, quero só fazer uma pesquisa no banco pra ir exibindo pelo site.

Comment: Mas pense numa dificuldade de encaixar esse usort no meu código.

Comment: Não consegui entender o motivo de não usar order by.

Comment: Como você faz o retorno da function "get_result"?

Comment: Não quero usar o order by em uma segunda query porque quero fazer só uma busca no banco, eu já tenho os dados em um SELECT *, entende? Quero otimizar o código pra utilizar a menor quantidade de buscas no banco

Comment: Bom, é tudo que está aí, eu pego o resultado da busca, uso o fetch array e exibo os dados em uma tabela, escolhendo quais colunas e quantos registros quero exibir, só que como vou utilizar uma query, preciso ordenar os dados fora da query.

Comment: Está difícil entender o seu código, ele está muito picado. A onde necessariamente você esta chamando o usort? Porque no "while" você esta pegando direto os resultados do banco. E também não entendi porque você teria quer fazer uma segunda query, não tem como já ordenar a primeira?

Comment: Não chamei o usort ainda, porque antes mesmo de chamar, dá esse erro, quero utilizar ele nesse while. Eu não vou fazer uma segunda query, quero ordenar a primeira mesmo.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM esc_usuarios WHERE usu_indicador_codigo = ? order by usu_indicador_codigo" não rola?

Comment: E você só quer mostrar 2 resultados?

Comment: não rola porque eu não quero alterar a query original,quero ordenar no while, só isso mesmo, ordenar os resultador por alguma coluna SEM SER na query

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** Como corrigido nos comentários, o erro "**Illegal string offset**" acontece quando tenta acessar o índice de uma string usando outra string (como explicado melhor na outra resposta).

E o erro "**Undefined offset**" (que eu havia erroneamente confundindo antes) acontece quando você tentar acessar um índice que não existe no array. 
Neste erro é possível usar o "**isset**" para checar e testar o valor do array antes de executar qualquer operação.

Comment: Removeu o erro, mas não retornou nenhum valor, preciso de algum while?

Comment: Não sei se influencia em algo, mas eu estou tentando fazer isso dentro uma session utilizando:
isset($_SESSION['codigo']);
$_SESSION['codigo'] = 1; 
$usu_codigo = $_SESSION['codigo'];

Comment: Como assim não retornou nenhum valor? o usort retorna um boolean, e a variável ordenada é a própria variável passada ($usu_info_coluna). Se puder, atualize a pergunta colocando as informações da session.

Comment: Perdão, erro meu. Como eu faço para usar esse resultado num while? Porque se eu usar assim:  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usu_info_coluna)), ele vai dizer que precisa de um result ao invés de um array

Comment: Errado. Geralmente, Illegal offset está relacionado com o tipo de valor passado para índice do `array`. O que aparece quando o offset não existe é "Undefined offset"

Comment: @LuannSousa não retornou valor nenhum porque, como eu disse na minha resposta, o seu `array` passado para `usort` está iterando sobre cada item. E cada item é um valor `int` ou `strng`, e não um `array`. Você terá que revisar como os dados do banco são retornados pra você.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção, confusão minha realmente.